# How to make chromecast a dlna receiver/client (indirectly)

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromecast, dlna

I got a chromecast, rPi, PC, iphone, android tablet.
The apps I want to cast live video from only support DLNA, and I want to watch those lives using chromecast.
I think it maybe kinda like this:

[1.Phone apps] -> [2.Conversion server] -> [3.Chromecast]

1.Phone apps can show a list of DLNA receiver to cast its live video to;

2.Conversion server can be detected as DLNA receiver, it receives lives sent from phone apps and convert them to something that chromecast supports in real-time, then send them to chromecast;

3.Chromecast is plugged to TV, it receives things from conversion server, so I can watch them on TV.

Let's say the server is shown as DLNA receiver [myRelay]. The use case would be like this:
I open my app on my phone, select where to cast live video to(which is myRelay) from detected device list, myRelay do the conversion thing and send them to chromecast, then I can watch live video on my TV.

The problem is, I don't know how to set up the server, what kind of sofwares out there I can use.

Maybe there is some kind of server that can run on rPi? I don't know. I'm new to this.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Pi, check out this instructable: https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Media-Server-MiniDLNA/

Keep in mind that depending on the model, the WiFi might chug when trying to stream high-bitrate content. It might be better to connect the Pi to the network via Ethernet.